# set date with year confusion in javascript Date()

Tags: javascript, date

According to w3schools :

```
There are 4 ways of initiating a date:

new Date()
new Date(milliseconds)
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

so when I try `console.log(new Date(2015));` it gave me `1970-01-01T00:00:02.015Z` ?

Comment: Because it matches the `Date(milliseconds)` overload. Try `new Date(2015, 0, 1)` instead

Comment: Even `console.log(new Date(2015, 0));` will give you the date you're looking for, since it tells the constructor that you're not using one with a single parameter.

Comment: @haim770 tried that gave me 2014.

Comment: @JessicaIlly—that should give 2015-01-01 00:00:00 in your host time zone. Anything else is not consistent with any version of [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms).

Comment: As usual, w3schools is not correct. You can also do `new Date(Date)`. Perhaps the authors should read the [*language specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-value). :-)

Answer (score 1):

It thinks that `2015` is the amount of milliseconds you want.

You could try using a calculator to see how many milliseconds the year 2015 is equivalent to, but it would be bad to maintain.

You should use one of the other ways you listed:

> new Date(dateString)

```
new Date('01/01/2015')
```

or

> new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)

```
new Date(2015,0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
console.log(new Date(milliseconds)
```

The docs on MDN state clearly:

> Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in time. Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.

Comment: While MDN is very helpful, the normative reference (i.e. "the docs") is [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-value). ;-)

Comment: Yup but it horrible to read. Also MDN, is curated content, so it's not wrong to quote. Not to mention it was founded by the man who invented JavaScript 

Comment: Not sure Brendan Eich has much to do with the content of the MDN (or if he ever did). It's a public wiki, anyone can contribute. Agree that ECMA-262 is turgid and getting worse. The online version is a backward step in terms of functionality, e.g. searching, over previous versions. But it's the standard. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You initialized it with a number, which actually means milliseconds or `new Date(milliseconds)`.

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
console.log(new Date('01/01/2015'));
```

If what you want is the current time or year, you can get it with

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.getFullYear());
```

Finally, I recommend you to read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) entries which are more accurate than W3Schools'.

Comment: Please don't suggest parsing strings with the Date constructor, especially one that isn't supported by the language standard.

Comment: I am not sure what is the standard string. Can you edit the answer to fit it? Thanks.